# How can I match a complex pattern in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

I have a table of allowed formats that I need to be able to lookup based on a string. Some example formats are:

- ^.^.testdomain.com
- ^.testdomain.com
- ^qwerty^.testdomain.com

I need to return one or more matching rows based on a sample input of:

- device.name.testdomain.com would return the first and second format
- johnqwertysmith.testdomain.com would return all the formats

Unfortunately the character '^' is fixed as the wildcard, this is a constraint I can't change.

I was hoping that perhaps regex could save me here, maybe using the format as the pattern and comparing it to the input. Regex is not something I have used much in the past so I'm not really sure of its capabilities. Failing that, is there any other way of performing this lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE @INPUT LIKE REPLACE(yourTable.savedFormat, '^', '%')
```

This won't allow you to leverage any indexs on your savedFormat column, but I suspect thats hopeless anyway for these requirements.